# Spark Dataframe / SQL - Complex enriching nested data

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

**Context**

I have an example of event source data in a dataframe input as shown below.

SOURCE

[image]

where eventOccurredTime is a String type.  This is from the source and I want to retain this in its original string form (with nano sec)

And I want to use the string to enrich some extra date/time typed data for downstream usage.  below is an example

TARGET

[image]

Now as a one off I can execute some spark sql on the dataframe as shown below to get the result I want:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

def transformDF(): DataFrame = {
  spark.sql(
   s"""
    SELECT 
      id,
      struct(
        event.eventCategory,
        event.eventName,
        event.eventOccurredTime,
        struct (
          CAST(date_format(event.eventOccurredTime,"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS") AS TIMESTAMP) AS eventOccurredTimestampUTC,
          CAST(date_format(event.eventOccurredTime,"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS") AS DATE) AS eventOccurredDateUTC,
          unix_timestamp(substring(event.eventOccurredTime,1,23),"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS") * 1000  AS eventOccurredTimestampMillis,
          datesDim.dateSeq AS eventOccurredDateDimSeq
        ) AS eventOccurredTimeDim,
```

NOTE: This is a snippet, for the full event, I have to do this explicitly in this long SQL 20 times for the 20 string dates

**Some things to point out:**

```
unix_timestamp(substring(event.eventOccurredTime,1,23)
```

Above I found I had to substring a date that had nano precision or would return null, hence the substring

```
xDim.xTimestampUTC
xDim.xDateUTC
xDim.xTimestampMillis
xDim.xDateDimSeq
```

above is the pattern / naming convention for the 4 nested xDim struct fields to derive and they are present in the predefined spark schema the json is read using to create the source dataframe.

```
 datesDim.dateSeq AS eventOccurredDateDimSeq
```

To get the above 'eventOccurredDateDimSeq' field, I need to join to a dates dimensions table 'datesDim' (static with an hourly grain), where dateSeq is the 'key' where this date falls into an hourly bucket where datesDim.UTC is defined to the hour

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN datesDim ON
      CAST(date_format(event.eventOccurredTime,"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:00:00") AS TIMESTAMP) = datesDim.UTC
```

The table is globally available in the spark cluster so should be quick to look up, but I need to do this for every date enrichment in the payloads and they will have different dates.

```
dateDimensionDF.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("datesDim")
```

The general schema pattern is that if there is a string date whose field name is:

```
x
```

..there is a 'xDim' struct equiv that immediately follows it in schema order below as described.

```
xDim.xTimestampUTC
xDim.xDateUTC
xDim.xTimestampMillis
xDim.xDateDimSeq
```

As mentioned with the snippet, although in the image above I am only showing 'eventOccuredTime' in above, there are more of these through the schema, at lower levels too, that need the same transformation pattern applied.

**Problem:**

So I have the spark sql (the full monty the snippet came from) to do this one off for 1 event type and its a large, explicit SQL statement that applies the time functions and joins I showed), but here is my problem I need help with.

So I want to try and create a more generic, functionally orientated reusable solution, that traverses a nested dataframe and applies this transformation pattern as described above 'where it needs to'

How do define 'where it needs to'?

Perhaps the naming convention is a good start - traverse the DF, look for any struct fields that have the xDim ('Dim' suffix) pattern, and use the 'x' field presceding as the input, and populate the xDim.* values in line with the naming pattern as described?

How in a function to best join on the datesDim registered table (its static remember) so it performs?

**Solution?**

Think one or more UDF is needed (we use Scala), maybe by itself or as a fragment within SQL, but not sure. Ensuring the DatesDim lookup performs is key I think.

Or maybe there is another way?

Note: I am working with Dataframes / SparkSQL not Datasets, options for each welcomed though?

**Databricks**

NOTE: Im actually using the databricks platform for this, so for those verse in SQL 'Higher order functions' in Dbricks

https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/higher-order-functions-lambda-functions.html

....is there a slick option here using 'TRANSFORM' as a SQL HOF (might need to register a utility UDF and use this with transform perhaps)?

Awesome, thanks spark community for your help!!!  Sorry this is a long post setting the scene.